# Reverse the array without using second one. ( C language)

Tags: c, arrays

Okay so i have created this code. I know there is a question regarding this problem but i dont know even with the suggested logic i am not getting the desired result. The output i am getting is the same array which i gave as input, its not reversing. C language is used in it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void revarray(int n, int arr[n])
{
    int i;
    int j=n-1;
    int temp;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        temp = arr[i];
        arr[i]=arr[j];
        arr[j]=temp;
        j--;
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    int i;
    printf("Enter the number of elements of array= ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int arr[n];
    printf("Enter the elements:\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter element %d= ",i);
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    }
    revarray(n,arr);
}
```

Comment: This has been asked 100 times. You have reversed the array twice, once between 0 and n/2, and then again to the end of the array. Use a debugger on a small example ....

Comment: `for(i=0;i<n;i++)` maybe should stop a bit sooner? Step through with a debugger or use some `printf` statements to see.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to run your reverse loop n/2 times.
because when you are swapping you are swapping from both sides, that's why you have to swap for n/2 times.

```
for(i=0;i<n/2;i++)
    {
        temp = arr[i];
        arr[i]=arr[j];
        arr[j]=temp;
        j--;
    }
```

Comment: Help me out in one more thing. Can you explain me whats happening in the following snippet

Comment: for(i=n;i>=pos;i--)
 {
  arr[i]=arr[i-1];
 }
Its the part of adding an element into an array, but i dont get this thing. how this will make space for new element

Comment: Can you edit or ask a new question for this part with your code ?

Answer (score 0):

You code is reversing the order of the array...twice. Picture how it works if the array has 2 elements - 5 and 10.

The loop starts with `i=0` and swaps arr[0] with arr[1].
Then `i` increments and it's still less than `n` so continues with `i=1` and swaps arr[1] with arr[0].

The solution is to only run the loop for half the array.